# JSONGenerator issue

Tags: apex, json, apexrest, java

I want to return a JSON from my Apex Rest web service. There is a list of objects I must return.
If I just make the return type of the method as

**return myCustObjList**

**Edit** here goes the datatype:

```
List<BusinessPartnerUpdateResult> myCustObjList = new 
List<BusinessPartnerUpdateResult>();

global class BusinessPartnerUpdateResult {
    global String SalesforceID {get; set;}
    global String success {get; set;}
    global List<ErrorDetails> errors {get; set;}
}
global class ErrorDetails {
    global String errorCode {get; set;}
    global String errorMessage {get; set;}
}
```

Here is how it gets populated... inside a loop of Database.SaveResult:

```
eachBusinessPartnerUpdateResult.SalesforceID = saveResult.getId();
if (saveResult.isSuccess()) {
    businessPartnerUpdateResult.success = 'true';
}
```

....

It works fine and in the Java caller I am getting back a nice JSON like this:

```
    [{
        "success": "true",
        "SalesforceID": "0011r00001mIDEPAA4",
        "errors": null
    }, {
        "success": "true",
        "SalesforceID": "0011r00001mIDEFAA4",
        "errors": null
    }, {
        "success": "true",
        "SalesforceID": "0011r00001mIDEAAA4",
        "errors": null
    }]
```

However, I wish to wrap the whole list in a JSON object and return that object instead.

So instead of **return myCustObjList** I have written this in my WS:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeObjectField('syncResults', myCustObjList);
gen.writeEndObject();
return gen.getAsString();
```

and changed the webservice method return type to String.

Now what Java gets back is this:

```
"{\"syncResults\":[{\"success\":\"true\",\"SalesforceID\":\"0011r00001mIDEPAA4\",\"errors\":null},{\"success\":\"true\",\"SalesforceID\":\"0011r00001mIDEFAA4\",\"errors\":null},{\"success\":\"true\",\"SalesforceID\":\"0011r00001mIDEAAA4\",\"errors\":null}]}"
```

Why are there so many backslash escape characters? Can I not get just the simple JSON as String minus the backslashes?
I have tried JSONGenerator "pretty" version, then I get back lots of \n, I do not want that either.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Just added definition..

Comment: Added code as to how it gets populated too ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the backslash you have to write the blob value of the JSON String into the body directly in the `RestContext`. You will have to change the return type of your method from String to void.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myrestservice/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account];
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('syncResults', accList);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        String jsonStr = gen.getAsString();
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(jsonStr);        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thats a fantastic suggestion..Thanks Saroj